# is dot product a binary operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products, binary-operations

something make me confused!
in the definition of binary operation we have :
“a binary operation on a set S is a mapping of the elements of the Cartesian product S × S to S:
F: s *s → s  “
it means binary operation is closure
my question is :
** is scalar product a binary operation?
because it’s not closure
it take two vector and result is a scalar!
and it is F:V * V → S

Comment: Speaking with the usual jargon, it's a binary operation, since it takes two values of the same set as arguments, but is not a closed (or inner) binary operation since the result of the operation does not live in the original set (except when the vector space is $\mathbb{R}$). However if we take your definition as an standard, it will not be a binary operation (your definition requires the operation to be closed).

Comment: Most definitions I've seen define a binary operation on a set $A$ to be a function from $A \times A$ to $A$. So we required it to be "closed"; that is, we take two elements of the set and output another element of the same set.